# How to use Firebase storage to existing project

Tags: rest, firebase

i want to integrate Firebase Storage to my actual project. I have a login system using a REST API. What should i do to have authentication and be able to upload files for each user with the correct permissions?

Thanks

EDIT:

I have a REST API and a VueJs frontend. Im actually doing JWT token authentication via the api. I dont know how to let firebase know my users and how to upload files for a specific user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at the firebase [security documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/)? They have a detailed break down on how to deal with authentication on a per-user basis.

This is quoted directly from the documentation page:

> When a user is authenticated with Firebase Authentication, the
>   request.auth variable in Storage Security Rules becomes an object that
>   contains the user's unique ID (request.auth.uid) and all other user
>   information in the token (request.auth.token). When the user is not
>   authenticated, request.auth is null. This allows you to securely
>   control data access on a per-user basis. You can learn more in the
>   User Security section.

What have you tried? What's not working?

Comment: I will read that documentation. But i dont think thats what im looking for. I dont know where to start. I have a REST API and a VueJs frontend. Im actually doing JWT token authentication via the api. I dont know how to let firebase know my users and how to upload files for a specific user. Thanks!